# TV Show/Movie from either the 80s or 90s where a kid needs to build a weapon of the right shape to defend the human race

Tags: story-identification

I have some distant memories of watching either a movie or a short in the 90s.

Premise: A kid is tasked by an "unknown entity" to build a weapon to defend the human race. He needs to find the perfect geometric shape for planet earth. The weapon is either a pyramid or a sphere. I can't remember.

Sorry I cannot give more details. It's starting to disappear from my mind.

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F.  Please check out the [suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/101407) for story-id questions to see if they help you recall any additional details you can [edit] into your question.

Comment: Was it live action or animated? English language or dubbed/subtitled, was it aimed at kids, young adult or adult? lots of information you could add that would help here!

Comment: Just on the off chance, are you thinking of the British Tv adaptation of Chocky by John Wyndham or possibly one of the sequel series Chocky's Children or Chocky's Challenge.  These stories deviated from Wyndham's original novel but there was lots of pyramid shaped imagery. Chocky's challenge revolved around a quest to harness cosmic energy rather than make a weapon. These were broadcast in the 1980's inn the UK and early 1990's in Canada and other provinces. here is the wiki... https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chocky_(TV_series)